# Using winhttpjs batch script in Windows, how do I upload a file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, winhttp, winhttprequest

I need to upload a file from a windows computer to a server on which I have full control. But since I don't have access to that computer, a technician will copy a minimal batch script with a schedule. So I chose [WINHTTPJS BATCH](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/winhttpjs.bat).

I already used it to download the file :

```
call winhttpjs.bat "http://192.168.1.248:8070/spectra/download-xls" -method GET -headers-file headers.txt -reportfile reportfile.txt -saveTo spectra_connect.xls
```

Now I need the command to specify the file to be uploaded. I tried :

```
call winhttpjs.bat "http://192.168.1.248:8070/spectra/upload-xls-files" -method POST -headers-file headers.txt -reportfile reportfile.txt -file spectra_connect.xls
```

But `-file spectra_connect.xls` option does not exist. I tried `-body-file`, but those seems to read the file contents to parse and push them. I can't even get how to send a field (like input) as the POST data. I need help on this. If I can't I'm gonna have to change to wget or curl which is more work for the remote technicians.

Comment: Switch to curl.

Comment: I'm thinking to do so. But I realized that winhttpjs.bat wasn't mean to do all that stuff. Instead, I'm trying to use the WinHttpRequest object itself of microsoft which has all the options. If I can't then I'll switch.

Comment: @shadow2020, at that time I ended using curl execution file, it's portable. In case anyone want to know. Also in 2020, I gained access to the PC connected with the devices, so I wrote a Whole Server with Node JS and Express, and everything went well.